# how to and where to put item in localstorage in store

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, redux, ionic2, ionic3

I'm using ionic 4 and angular. also plugin - ng2-redux.

I dispatch an event. I catch it in store. I put the caught item in store but what I also need is to put that item in localStorage. As you know, I don't have window.localStorage, since I'm developing ionic app. so I need to include Storage module and I also need a constructor to inject it, but I don't have a constructor in store. and people also say not to write putting items in localstorage in reducer. so what Do I do?

```
import { SET_USER_ROLE } from "./actions";
import { Storage } from '@ionic/storage'
export interface IUsersState{
    access_token : string,
    refresh_token :string, 
    role_name: string,
    data: Object
}

export const USERS_INITIAL_STATE: IUsersState = {
    access_token: null,
    refresh_token: null,
    role_name: null,
    data : null
}

export function usersReducer(state: IUsersState = USERS_INITIAL_STATE, action) : IUsersState{
    switch(action.type){
        case SET_USER_ROLE =>{
            // I want to put role_name in localstorage but to do that, i have to write 
            // this.storage.set (but storage needs to be injected in constructor, but i don't have one)
            // also it's said that it's bad to put it in localstorage at this place reducer.
            return {...state, role_name: action.role_name};
        }
    }
    return state;
}
```

Comment: if you were to use ngrx store instead, you could use this... https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngrx-6-store-ionic-storage

Comment: you think it's impossible to follow my implementation? I didn't want to move to another package for now. :/

Comment: Canonically you want to use Effect to perform saving to storage. So once store is updated a side effect should be persisting the item. Btw why do you think localStorage is not available?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [intel security](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/intel-security/) plugin.